# error in extend activity You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme

Tags: android

I am styling the action bar. I am having this error `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity` I know I should extend `Activity` in my main activity however I am extending `AppCompatActivity` because  I am  using this code       `setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);` If I removed `AppCompatActivity` will not work therefor I will not be able to use bottom toolbar;

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
private void initToolbars() {

    Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);

    Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_settings:
                    // Single menu item is selected do something
                    // Ex: launching new activity/screen or show alert message
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bookmark is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_save:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_search:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                case R.id.menu_share:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Share is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
    toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);

}
```

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.je.www.i" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

styles

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: post the AndroidManifest.xml and your styles.xml

Comment: @Blackbelt check now please

Comment: Change the `parent` of your `CustomActionBarTheme` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: @Blackbelt I had error This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Theme` should be like

```
 <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

set parent as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: I got this error `This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead` I guess from the method I have created.

Comment: @Moudiz  I don't understand what's your problem??

Comment: there was something in my code anyway I adjuste it thanks

Comment: @Moudiz ok fine but look at Blackbelt answer. Could solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change your theme like

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

this way you will not request the ActionBar and you should be able to use the toolbar, or better use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, since you want to use the `ToolBar` and you don't need the `ActionBar`. Using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` you don't need to provide the flag `windowActionBar` to your style

Comment: in your case using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` would be better